# spring flyway docker connection to localhost:5432 refused

Tags: spring, docker, flyway

I have a spring application with flyway and psql. After

```
mvn clean install
sudo docker build -t air-travels-api.jar .
docker run -p 8080:8080 air-travels-api.jar
```

I stuck with an error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.

2022-07-09 14:28:09.610  WARN 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException: Unable to obtain connection from database: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

Here's my docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  air-travels-api:
    image: air-travels-api
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: air-travels-api
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - flyway
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://air-travels-api-db:5432/air-travels-api
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=postgres
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=postgres
      - SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO=update
  flyway:
    image: boxfuse/flyway:5-alpine
    command: -url=jdbc:postgresql://air-travels-api-db:5432/air-travels-api -schemas=public -user=postgres -password=postgres migrate
    volumes:
      - ./migration:/flyway/sql
    depends_on:
      - air-travels-api-db
    environment:
        - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
        - POSTGRES_DB=air-travels-api
        - POSTGRES_HOST=postgres
        - POSTGRES_PORT=5432
        - POSTGRES_SCHEMA=public
  air-travels-api-db:
    image: postgres:12
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    container_name: air-travels-api-db
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: air-travels-api
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk:11-jre-hotspot
EXPOSE 8080
ADD target/air-travels-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar air-travels-api.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/air-travels-api.jar"]
```

Applicaton.yaml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://air-travels-api-db:5432/air-travels-api
    username: postgres
    password: postgres
```

I found a similar question on stackoverflow, they suggested making sure postgres is running on the local machine. But I have it running inside a container (air-travels-api-db).

Comment: The `environment: [SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=...]` should (correctly) override the Spring properties you show.  Is the application code itself trying to run Flyway at application startup time (if so, you don't need a separate container) and does that have a separate location; do you know where else the `localhost:5432` might be coming from?

Comment: (The `flyway` container consistently has the wrong database host name, `postgres` instead of `air-travels-api-db`, but that doesn't match your error message.)

Comment: The error message is not matched because `docker-compose` didn't execute that far, and failed before it could go to that point. You're right to identify the misconfiguration.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues that I see:

1. In the `Application.yaml` your `url` should be

```
jdbc:postgresql://air-travels-api-db:5432/air-travels-api
```

since your database service has the hostname `air-travels-api-db` and not `localhost`.

2. In your `flyway` service in `docker-compose.yaml`, the `url` is also incorrect. It should point to `air-travels-api-db` instead of `postgres`.

```
    command: -url=jdbc:postgresql://api-travels-api-db:5432/air-travels-api -schemas=public -user=postgres -password=postgres migrate
```

You do set the environment variable, but it is possible the command-line argument will override that.

> One suggestion: Database containers are known to have a slow startup, therefore, it is a good idea to either add a `health-check` to your database service, or make sure to implement retry logic in your application. Otherwise, you will see race condition issues where the application runs before the database is available and it crashes. This is very common.

Comment: I fixed it (attached to the question), but still encountering the same error